# Content-Disposition header visible in preview but not actually available

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core, http-headers, content-disposition

I am running into this weird issue with my .NET Core API download functionality where I append a Content-Disposition header from my controller, but it doesn't end up reaching the client. With some debugging I found the following: I can see the Content-Disposition header in the preview of the content's headers' object, but not in the full overview of the same object, which I don't understand. See the following screenshots:

[image: In the preview of the content's headers, I see the Content-Disposition header]

[image: However, when I expand the object it shows that Content-Disposition is null]

It also appears I can not use the value of the header in my code.
Can anybody help me with this issue?

**EDIT:** I have found out the header is stored under NonValidated as seen in the bottom screenshot. Now I'm not sure what this means, so any help would be appreciated ! :)

Comment: If you used `Add(string, string)` to add the header, just make sure you typed the name correctly.

Comment: @shingo I added it as follows:
`Response.Headers.Append("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);`

Comment: Your first screenshot shows you were inspecting an `HttpConnectionResponseContent` object which is different from `HttpResponse`.